# How to guard from chef-client state of last block run; don't use state file

Tags: linux, github, chef-infra, chef-recipe

**disclaimer**: pretty new to chef and I've inherited a bunch of chef cookbooks. The methods below are sub-optimal but it is what I have to work with for now. Be gentle, please. :) Also, please bear with me as I try to describe what I need.

Please note that we are using chef-client 11.16.4. Updating to 12.x, for now, is not an option.

tl;dr
Is there a way to specify a guard from the state of the current running block:

```
...
only_if { this_block_did_something }
notifies :run, 'bash[deploy-custom-docker-container]', :immediately
```

OK....

Take this chunk of code in a recipe I inherited and need to refactor a little...

```
# The identities of the innocent have been changed for their 
# protection. Please ignore odd things in this example:

application app[:name] do
   path app[:deploy_path]
   enable_submodules true
   repository app[:repository]
   owner OWNER
   group GROUP
   symlinks({
       "file.py" => "path/file.py"
   })
   revision app[:branch]
   deploy_key data_bag_item('deployment_keys', 'keyname')['private_key']
end

link "/path/to/file.py" do
   to "/path/to/settings-%s.py" % [file]
end

# This is where I need some direction...I think.
# note that CMD is a valid constant and the custom docker 
# container does not follow any industry standard docker 
# conventions due to our strange use-case. So I had to resort
# using a bash block to call our custom start/stop/restart script

bash 'deploy-custom-docker-container' do
  code <<-EO
  #{CMD} restart
  EO

  # currently a subscribes but I've tried other methods which 
  # don't achieve what I'm trying to accomplish
  subscribes :run, 'application[%s]' % [app[:name]]
end
```

The `application app[:name]` deploys source code onto the target node whenever the repo has new code to be synced. The `bash` block restarts a very custom and non-industry standard docker container which uses the code.

In its current form, which is undesirable, the `bash[deploy-custom-docker-container]` block always gets executed irrespective of whether `application app[:name]` has to deploy code to a git repo or not (IE repo is up to date vs not up to date) on the target node. I'm sure I could create some code that determines if the repo was updated, touch a state/lock file, and then `guard` execution of the `bash` block by checking if that lockfile exists. To me, that would be a sub-optimal way to achieve my goal. What would be optimal is to use chef's state of the update as the method of setting the guard. Is that possible?? Read on...

In other words, when `application app[:name]` is hit during chef-client runtime, and a repo has been updated (and thus deployed on the node), chef-client reports the steps of `application app[:name]` deploying the new code. If the repo didn't need to be updated, chef-client happily skips the block with a "(up to date)" message. If the repo needed to be updated, chef-client shows the steps taken to deploy the code. So chef-client knows the state of the block of code it just ran.

Also, my observations of how chef-client runs in our environment has shown me that it doesn't matter if I put a `notifies` block in `application app[:name]` for `bash[deploy-custom-docker-container]` or use the `subscribes` method (pasted above); the `bash` block gets run irrespective of the state of the `application app[:name]`. I'd prefer that if the `application app[:name]` doesn't have an update to perform then the `bash` block doesn't run.

What I fear is that I will have to use a state file to determine the state of the update of the repo from the `application app[:name]` block. I'd rather just guard off the state of the run-time from chef's perspective of the `application app[:name]` block.

**FIXED CODE**

As pointed out by [zts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365624/zts), my `action`s were wrong or missing. The following code is what I was able to come up with that resolved my issue.

```
application app[:name] do
   ...

   notifies :run, 'link[%s]' % [filetolink], :immediately
end

link filetolink do
   to file

   notifies :run, 'bash[deploy-custom-docker-container]', :immediately
end

bash 'deploy-custom-docker-container' do
  code <<-EO
  #{CMD} restart
  EO

  action :nothing
end
```

This works for me now.

Comment: The old application cookbook that you are using, the one that works on Chef 11, was not at all careful about how it set the `updated?` flags. This is part of why it was completely rewritten about 6 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notifications only fire if the notifying resource has changed (and the other way around, subscriptions only fire if the resource you're subscribing to has changed).

The reason the bash block runs irrespective of the notification is that, by default, bash blocks will run.  If you only want a resource to run when notified, make sure to include `action :nothing`.

ie:

```
bash 'deploy-custom-docker-container' do
  code <<-EO
  #{CMD} restart
  EO

  action :nothing
  subscribes :run, 'application[%s]' % [app[:name]]
end
```

Comment: Thank you @zts. I've updated the post to show how I refactored the code.